Pipeline Shows as Failed When Successful
My Azure DevOps pipeline pulls a Docker image and creates 5 containers. One container sets up the other 4 and then exits, indicating successful setup. However, Azure Pipelines marks the pipeline as failed due to the 'Exited' status, even though everything is functioning correctly.
My only fix is adding continueOnError: true, but this only flags the pipeline with a warning. I also tried condition: succeededOrFailed(), but it still marks the pipeline as failed.
Here is an example of the logs:
2024-07-01T14:47:08.8069778Z ##[error] Container airflow-postgres-1  Healthy
2024-07-01T14:47:08.8073598Z ##[error] Container airflow-postgres-1  Healthy
2024-07-01T14:47:08.8075304Z ##[error] Container airflow-redis-1  Healthy
2024-07-01T14:47:18.3181399Z ##[error] Container airflow-airflow-init-1  Exited  Container airflow-airflow-init-1  Exited  Container airflow-airflow-init-1  Exited

Any guidance or tips to handle this in the azure-pipelines.yml would be most appreciated, I would love the pipeline to continue processing the Pipeline instead of marking as Exited thus generating a Failed job.
Here is a relevant sample of the azure-pipelines.yml.
  - task: SSH@0
    inputs:
      sshEndpoint: $(SSH_SERVICE_CONNECTION)
      runOptions: 'inline'
      inline: |
        az login --identity
        az acr login --name $(IMAGE_REGISTRY)

        cd $(PROJECT_DIR)
        export AIRFLOW_UID=$(AIRFLOW_UID) 
        export PROJECT_DIR=$(PROJECT_DIR)

        docker pull $(IMAGE_REGISTRY).azurecr.io/$(IMAGE_NAME):latest
        docker compose -f docker-compose.prod.yaml up -d
    continueOnError: true


It might be helpful to see the script, or at least the relevant part of it.

@RuiJarimba thank you for the suggestion I have included the relevant part of the azure pipeline yaml.

It looks like for some reason, these logs are written to stderr. As per docs, the default behavior of the SSH task is to fail the task when something is written to stderr. To disable this behavior, set the failOnStdErr option to false:
  - task: SSH@0
    inputs:
      sshEndpoint: $(SSH_SERVICE_CONNECTION)
      runOptions: 'inline'
      failOnStdErr: false
      inline: |
        az login --identity
        az acr login --name $(IMAGE_REGISTRY)

        cd $(PROJECT_DIR)
        export AIRFLOW_UID=$(AIRFLOW_UID) 
        export PROJECT_DIR=$(PROJECT_DIR)

        docker pull $(IMAGE_REGISTRY).azurecr.io/$(IMAGE_NAME):latest
        docker compose -f docker-compose.prod.yaml up -d

Note that in this case, actual errors also may not fail the pipeline.
